# Setting dynamic text(record count) in an @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an HTML Action Link as

```
 <div>@Html.ActionLink("New Requests>", "GetNewRequests", "Resource", null, new { @class = "spbutton" })</div>
```

Which displays on a page as a link "New Requests >" when clicked it shows a grid of the requests.

I now need this link to be "New Requests (x)>" ex( New Requests(4)) where x is the count of the number of new requests, also equal to the number of rows in a grid.

I am not sure how to dynamically add the text the Html.ActionLink call.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a property to your view model containing this information. Have the controller action populate it. And then it's trivial:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(
        "New Requests (" + Model.TotalRequestsCount + ")>", 
        "GetNewRequests", 
        "Resource", 
        null, 
        new { @class = "spbutton" }
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a property

```
public int RequestCount {get; set;}
```

in your viewModel for the view.  Populate the property at the same time you make the call to get the requests and populate the grid.
Then you link would be

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("New Requests("+@Model.RequestCount+") >", "GetNewRequests", "Resource", null, new { @class = "spbutton" })</div>
```